# left- and right limit calculation (decide positive or negative absolute value)

Tags: limits

I have this assignment:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{|x-2|}{x-2}$$

I could probably do the calculation by just setting x to zero:

$\frac{|0-2|}{0-2}$ = $\frac{|-2|}{-2}$ = $\frac{2}{-2}$ = -1, which is correct (there is just one limit).

But, because it is a absolute value in this limit, I would like to separate it into two calculations, one for left and one for right, but something is getting wrong with the left calculation:

$$\lim_{x \to 0-}\frac{|x-2|}{x-2} = \begin{Bmatrix} x<0 \Rightarrow \\ x-2<-2 \Rightarrow \\ |x-2| = x-2 \end{Bmatrix} = \lim_{x->0-}\frac{x-2}{x-2} = \frac{0-2}{0-2} = \frac{-2}{-2} = 1$$

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in saying that $x-2<-2 \Rightarrow |x-2|=x-2$. In fact, if $x-2<-2$ then in particular $x-2<0$, so $|x-2|=-(x-2)$.

You'd get different left- and right-limits as $x \to 2$, but for $x \to 0$ everything's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Note that while $x\to 0$ , in fact, $x$ is so close to $0$ from both sides so in both cases $x<2$. See the following animated plot:

[image]

Comment: Beautiful graphics +1

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not see it, you can consider instead

> $$ \lim_{t\to -2} \frac{|t|}{t} ,$$

by putting $x-2=t$. Now, just consider left and right limits 
at the point $t=-2$.